# Ensuring customer requirements are clear

Tags: prince2, management, pmbok

As a new Project Manager what techniques and tactics exist to ensure the requirements of the project are as clear as possible and consensus is achieved about the delivery outcome.

In this context I am referring to a sponsor or the most senior stakeholder available.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework question

Comment: Hi Matthias, although I am really willing to help you, PM.SE is not the place for homework questions.

Comment: My apologies, first time user. I was seeking the assistance of a friend who directed me here. Due to my time constraints I quickly published my questions without taking it into consideration.

Comment: No worries - that's OK.  I would suggest raising another question with a concrete case study.  For instance "My team do not display full understanding of the project; what methods exist to ensure the team understands the project scope and also buys into the value of the delivery?"  I will edit this question to make it more suitable about customer requirements.

Comment: @venture2099 as you can tell I'm a novice, would you still be willing to give me some insight? The power point slides the course has provided beat around the bush quite a bit

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I hope my name isn't too tarnished now ;P

Comment: Course not.  I have edited the question but you should still raise a new question about the team delivery and understanding issue.

Comment: While homework questions aren't inherently off-topic, list-generating questions are. Entire books are written on this subject. A good question on Stack Exchange is targeted, has the possibility of a canonical answer, and isn't open to a wide range of opinions on what's *possible*.

Given a real-world problem with sufficient context, this question might be answerable. As it is, though, the possible answers are the entire fields of project management, stakeholder management, and meeting facilitation.

Answer (score 1):

According to the PMBOK Standard, requirements are part of Scope Management.

"requirements .. as clear as possible and consensus is achieved about the delivery outcome." is the activity of Requirements elicitation, which is

"Elicitation is the activity of drawing out information from stakeholders and other sources to further understand the needs of the business, in order to address a problem or opportunity and identify the stakholders' preferences and conditions for the solution that will address those needs." (Requirements Management by PMI)

To achieve clarity, a range of activities should be performed. To write 'excellent requirement', Chapter 11 of [[1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735679665)] suggest to check if requirements are

- Complete
- Correct
- Feasible
- Necessary
- Prioritized
- Unambiguous!
- Verifiable!

You should apply a clean writing approach, e.g. [precondition][trigger]software shall[response].

Additionally, consult IETF's RFC 2119, which contains information on requirements key words.

All this can lead you to the modelling of use cases, requirements, etc. see UML etc.

References:

[Software Requirements by Wiegers & Beatty](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735679665)